# Create a dynamic LINQ to SQL selector upon query execution

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to have a selector on an IQueryable query, which will be dynamically built upon the query execution:

```
IQueryable<Row> query = 
    from row in table
    select <byDynamicSelector>

<byDynamicSelector> = row => new Row { Value1 = row.Value1, Value2 = 0 };
Row[] rows1 = query.ToArray(); //Here I will get all the rows with Value2 = 0

<byDynamicSelector> = row => new Row { Value1 = 0, Value2 = row.Value2 };
Row[] rows2 = query.ToArray(); //Here I will get all the rows with Value1 = 0
```

Since the query is actually executed by a third party code, I need to have the ability to change the selector just before it is actually being executed.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Additional Clarifications:

Altough I was adviced to use expression trees which can be built dynamically, they are being built only **once** before any further executions. 
What I need, is to build a dynamic projection (select) before **any** execution. This is because I need to have different projections which are know at query execution time.

I was suggested to implement my own `IQueryProvider` to achieve that, but what is the simplest way to just inject my desired projection?

Comment: What have you tried to do? what went wrong? this is not supposed to be an outsourcing site...

Comment: @barakcaf My problem is more complex than this question (my case is a query that is used by DevExpress' GridControl, and my goal was to add empty group lines according to the grid's grouped columns). Nothing went wrong - I just couldn't find a way to achieve what I needed...

Comment: So you always know the query result type (e.g. `Row`) but want to dynamically control the projection (which fields are included in `Select`) in order to optimize the data retrieval (generated SQL query)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes!

Comment: Cool. What you have as input - list of property names, list of expressions or ? Can you provide a sample usage case.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have a list of property names, which are actually, in my real case, the columns which the grid is grouping by. So in my real case, suppose a user made a group by Value1 column, I wish to have all the distinct rows of (Value1, 0), which will be used as empty group lines.